# responsive canvas for different screens - best way to do it?

Tags: html, css, canvas, responsive-design, html5-canvas

so i have a canvas element just doing some background animations for an app.
my question is, whats the best way to make sure it looks the same on different devices?

am i best making different size canvas elements and using CSS media quires?
or is there a way to make the canvas flexible and responsive to fill 100% of the viewport using JS or html?

any help would be great!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Canvas Resize</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the width and height of the canvas. Don't use CSS to set canvas size as this affects only the element but not its bitmap (your canvas bitmap/image will be stretched).

Here is one way:

```
/// assuming canvas variable exists in global scope

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

resizeCanvas();    /// call the first time page is loaded

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

You can then add CSS rules to the canvas element:

```
#myCanvas {
    position:fixed; /* or absolute (or not..) depending on your goal */
    left:0;
    top:0;
    }
```

Your document `html` and `body` must also be setup properly with CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    }
```

If you want to cover the whole window also add `overflow: hidden` to the last CSS rule to avoid any scroll-bars.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, Yep...use Ken's idea instead of just resizing with CSS which distorts the original canvas drawings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `100%` variable.

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```